# Access multi - select picklist selected values in Apex Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, multi-select, selectoption

I have the following multi-select picklist code in my Visualforce page

```
<apex:selectList styleClass="form-control evemin" id="testid" size="3" multiselect="true" value="{!testVariable}" >
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="test1" itemValue="test1"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="test2" itemValue="test2"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="test3" itemValue="test3"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

testvariable is a String array variable in my apex class. Is this a proper way to pass  the value in Controller. What I can see is that it does not take the selected option to Apex class in this process. Is there any other way to do this

Comment: how do you want to pass the value to controller? is that based on button click or after selection of picklist values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link [apex:selectList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm), which is the correct way to handle multi-select picklist

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList value="{!countries}" multiselect="true">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectList><p/>

        <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
        <apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="testing...">
            <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputPanel>
                    <p>You have selected:</p>
                    <apex:dataList value="{!countries}" var="c">{!c}</apex:dataList>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class sampleCon {
        String[] countries = new String[]{};
        //If multiselect is false, countries must be of type String
        //String countries;

        public PageReference test() {
            return null;
        }

        public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));
            return options;
        }

        public String[] getCountries() {
            //If multiselect is false, countries must be of type String
            return countries;
        }

        public void setCountries(String[] countries) {
            //If multiselect is false, countries must be of type String
            this.countries = countries;
        }
    }
```